# How to correctly typeset an author's two-word last name in BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex

Using BibTeX, I would like to cite a paper by an author whose last name has two words. The reason why this is an issue is that if I just write `Jan A. Van Mieghem` in the author field of the .bib file, BibTeX will treat "Mieghem" as the last name and "Jan A. Van" as the first name, which isn't correct. I have seen two ways of correcting this:

> `Jan A. {Van Mieghem}` and `Van Mieghem, Jan A.`

Are these two handled the same by BibTeX? If not, what is the difference, and which one should be preferred?

Comment: Prefer `author={Van Mieghem, Jan A.}`, it's clearer.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. What do you mean by "clearer" though? To a human reader?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Patashnik's [btxdoc.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) covers names in some detail (search for "von").

Comment: This varies based on both conventions of the culture of origin (it's different for Dutch vs. German, for example), and would be determined by a style guide like *The Chicago Manual of Style*.

Comment: @FangJing In German or Dutch I don't know how the rule works, but sometimes in Spanish, it's suggested to combine both surnames with a hyphen. If you use `biblatex`instead, you can use `babel` or `polyglossia` and also use the `langid`field for compose it correctly.

Comment: @musarithmia You can check [Refering to someone whose name has an aristocratic particle](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/390996/236922) on english.SE for that regard.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, some examples of names with Two-word surnames

```
Charles De Gaulle
Martin Van Buren
Kristin Scott Thomas
Helena Bonham Carter
Antonio Garcia Pascual
Marco Del Negro
Vincent Van Gogh
Piero Della Francesca [also written as "Piero della Francesca"]
```

(In case you're curious: The first two are former Presidents of their respective countries; the middle two are actresses; the next two are professional economists; and the final two are painters. Vincent, hopefully, needs no special introduction...)

With all of these names, it would be quite wrong (i) to typeset their names as C. D. Gaulle, M. V. Buren, K. S. Thomas, etc. or (ii) to generate citation call-outs of the form "Negro and Pascual 2015". (Correct: Del Negro and Garcia Pascual 2015.)

To inform BibTeX that it's not dealing with authors (or editors...) with one first name, one middle name (De, Van, Scott, Bonham, etc), and one surname and, instead, with authors/editors that all have one first name and a two-word surname, the names should be entered into the `author` and `editor` fields either as (using commas)

```
De Gaulle, Charles
Van Buren, Martin
Scott Thomas, Kristin
Bonham Carter, Helena
Garcia Pascual, Antonio
Del Negro, Marco
Van Gogh, Vincent
Della Francesca, Piero
```

or as (using curly braces)

```
Charles {De Gaulle}
Martin {Van Buren}
Kristin {Scott Thomas}
Helena {Bonham Carter}
Antonio {Garcia Pascual}
Marco {Del Negro}
Vincent {Van Gogh}
Piero {Della Francesca}
```

I personally prefer the first of the two possibilities.

Turning to the final part of your query: Both `Jan A. {Van Mieghem}` and `Van Mieghem, Jan A.` are syntacically correct, in the sense that BibTeX has enough information to figure out what the surname component is. That said, I personally prefer the second form, viz., `Van Mieghem, Jan A.`.

---

Aside: Note that the case of names containing a two-word surname is quite distinct from the case of names that contain a "von component" and a single-word surname.

Comment: I believe that *Monsieur le Président* was, in fact, 'Charles *de* Gaulle' (note the lowercase 'd'). It's worthy of mention because *a)* I'm a pedant, and because *b)* BibTeX would, in fact, render 'Charles de Gaulle' correctly, as 'C. de Gaulle' – I gather that it's 'smart' enough to assume that a lowercase 'middle' name is part of / a prefix of the surname.

Comment: See also Mico's comment, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204697/how-to-correctly-typeset-an-authors-two-word-last-name-in-bibtex#comment570351_240057

Comment: @owjburnham - My bad! In case you're curious, I had initially considered using the name `Valéry Giscard d'Estaing` for this answer, but I didn't like the fact that the *second* part of that surname started with a lowercase letter. I then fell back on CDG;  obviously, I should have verified the correct spelling of his name more thoroughly...

Comment: And I didn't see that you were the same person as the Mico who wrote that comment. So my bad!

Comment: Not sure, whether this is ever relevant, but wouldn't encapsulating with curly braces also always preserve the case (e.g. meaning they can never be converted to lowercase in case the citation style requires that)? Possibly there are other, more relevant examples.

Comment: @clel - I know of no bib style that changes the case of letters in words (here: names) contained in the `author` abd `editor` fields.

Comment: Alright. But the theoretical problem is seems to be correct, then.

Comment: @ciel - Maybe it's a problem in theory but not in practice?

Answer (score 4):

BibTex allows in this case possible forms for the name:

```
"Jan A. {van Mieghem}"
"{van Mieghem}, Jan A."
```

You can use the curly braces {} to isolate parts that you want to keep together.

Both ways are fine.

Source: [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf)

Comment: Instead of parentheses, don't you mean curly braces?

Comment: Indeed. { and }.

Comment: This answer does *not* address the original query. As far as BibTeX is concerned, there's a significant difference between `Jan A. Van Mieghem` (what the OP wrote) and `Jan A. van Mieghem` (what you're writing). Your form of the name has, using BibTeX jargon, a "von component", as `van` is written with a lower-case "v". Observe that this is *not* the case in the form of the name that the OP was concerned with. Using the default parsing rules, BibTeX will interpret `Van` as a middle name instead of as the name's "von component". Please amend your answer to fix this discrepancy.

Comment: The brackets solution has proved relevant for another related situation the case of Pline l'Ancien. I succeeded in producing a correct reference with `author = {{Pline l'Ancien}}`