# Shortcut/macro for surrounding words with brackets

Tags: macros, bibtex, texstudio

When using BibTeX I usually need to fix broken capitalization by surrounding words with brackets (as answered in [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file)).

I also use this to fix some issues with author names containing hyphens when writing my .bib file. (Somehow related: [How to correctly typeset an author's two-word last name in BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204697/how-to-correctly-typeset-an-authors-two-word-last-name-in-bibtex))

Is there a keyboard shortcut on TeXstudio that surrounds a selected word with brackets? If not, how can I do it with a macro?

Edit: I've been usingTeXstudio to edit the .bib file, but it can probably be done with another editor such as Notepad++.

Comment: Can it be done on the entire bibtex file for all titles at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a TeXstudio macro that I use for exactly the purpose you mention:

```
%SCRIPT
txt = cursor.selectedText()
editor.write("{"+txt+"}")
cursor.clearSelection()
```

One you have added this in the Edit Macros window (I used "Braces Around Text" as the Name and left the other fields blank), you can assign it a keyboard shortcut in Configure TeXstudio | Shortcuts. It will be listed under Menus | Macros.

Comment: Can it be done on the entire bibtex file for all titles at once?