# Ancient names with nicknames and no surname in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, author

Is there a way to introduce ancient names in Bibtex and keeping all the parts together.
Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=apa,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{Bibliography.bib}
@book{Dionysius1613Dop,
    publisher = {In Collegio Regali in usum schole Etonens},
    year = {1613},
    title = {Dionysiou oikoumenēs periēgēsis.},
    address = {Etonæ},
    author = {Dionísio Periegeta},
    keywords = {Geography, Ancient -- sigla},
}

@book{Dionysius1974Tce,
    publisher = {Harvard University Press ; Heinemann},
    booktitle = {The critical essays},
    year = {1974},
    title = {The critical essays / Dionysius of Halicarnassus ; with an English translation by Stephen Usher.},
    address = {Cambridge, Mass. : London},
    author = {Dionísio de Halicarnasso},
    keywords = {Essays -- Translations into English; Greek literature -- History and criticism; Rhetoric, Ancient; Literary style},
}

@book{Menander2019MR,
    year = {2019},
    title = {Menander Rhetor ; (Dionysius of Halicarnassus), Ars rhetorica / edited and translated by William H. Race.},
    author = {Menandro Retor},
    keywords = {Rhetoric -- sigla},
}

@book{Didymus1975DtB2,
    publisher = {Hain},
    booktitle = {De trinitate, Buch 2, Kap. 1-7},
    year = {1975},
    title = {De trinitate, Buch 2, Kap. 1-7 / Didymus der Blinde ; hrsg. u. übers. von Ingrid Seiler},
    address = {Meisenheim am Glan},
    author = {Dídimo-o-Cego},
    keywords = {Holy Spirit -- sigla},
}

@book{didymus2016commentary,
    title={Commentary on Genesis},
    author={Didymus (the Blind)},
    url={https://books.google.pt/books?id=vQ-kDAAAQBAJ},
    year={2016},
    publisher={Catholic University of America Press},
}

@book{Pliny2013Pty,
    year = {2013},
    title = {Pliny, the younger : Epistles book II / edited by Christopher Whitton},
    language = {eng;lat},
    author = {{Plínio-o-Moço}},
    keywords = {Plínio-o-Moço -- sigla},
}

\end{filecontents}



\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}


\begin{document}

Um texto precisa de citações. Eis tal autor (\cite{Pliny2013Pty}), soubesse-o de cor!
Mas uma apenas não basta. Por isso, eis a segunda (\cite{Didymus1975DtB2}) e até uma terceira (\cite{didymus2016commentary}).
Uma citação é como uma muleta e eu preciso de outra agora (\cite{Menander2019MR}).
Fosse eu citado em obra de grande profundidade, de preferência, como esta (\cite{Dionysius1613Dop}).
Se só citar este autor (\cite{Dionysius1974Tce}) fosse garantia de que o li!

\begin{refsection}[Bibliography.bib]
\printbibliography[title=Coisas]
\nocite{*}
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

I am writing in Portuguese, but I suppose the problem is similar in other languages. In German, Didymus the Blind is Didymus der Blind. It would make no sense to write in the bibliography "Didymus" (or Dídimo in Portuguese).
The same applies to Menander. If you write it like that it will be taken as the dramatist. That is the reason why "Rhetor" is added.
If one writes Dionysius alone, it will be misleading: Dionysius the Areopagite? Dionysius Periegetes? Dionysius of Halicarnassus?

So how can I obtain the following author names with all the parts working as one name?
Dídimo-o-Cego (1975). Commentary on Genesis
Dionísio Periegeta (1613). Dionysiou oikoumenēs periēgēsis.
Plínio-o-Moço (2013). Epistles book II

I have tried curly braces as stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204697/how-to-correctly-typeset-an-authors-two-word-last-name-in-bibtex) without success.
Note: Two entries (didymus2016commentary) and (Didymus1975DtB2) were not identified by biber, I don't why. Still it is a good example of an ancient name with with no surname and only a proper name, very common, that is distinguished from others by the nickname attached to it.

Comment: It is usually bad advice to mix `style=apa,` with different styles. `biblatex-apa`'s `apa` style was written specifically to implement APA style. Mixing it with other styles kinds of defeats the purpose and was not intended when the style was written. There may be errors, warnings or silently weird behaviour. Unless you need APA style, I suggest you stick with `style=authoryear,`.

Comment: The `\begin{refsection}[Bibliography.bib]
\printbibliography[title=Coisas]
\nocite{*}
\end{refsection}` construction is a bit unusual and serves no sensible purpose in the example code (it could be different in your actual file). In this example you get much better results if you replace the whole block by `\printbibliography[title=Coisas]` and even in a more complex document I suspect there are better ways to do whatever you need to do than this.

Answer (score 1):

[image: example]

One possible solution (and by-passing `refsection` and `\nocite` for the moment):

(1) Start with a clean folder (just the `.tex` file, in the MWE).

(2) For the bib entries, use `family={}`, like this: `author = {family={Dionísio Periegeta}},`

(3) For biblatex, specify *bib* style and cite style: `\usepackage[bibstyle=apa,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}`. The `style=` option sets both bibstyle and citestyle.

(4) Compile with lualatex/biber/lualatex, as usual.

How it works: if biblatex/biber and the styles are using family name as the identifier (for sorting etc), put the `X-of-Y`-type of name as the identifier, even though it looks and sounds like (and is) given name + nickname.

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}

@book{Dionysius1613Dop,
    publisher = {In Collegio Regali in usum schole Etonens},
    year = {1613},
    title = {Dionysiou oikoumenēs periēgēsis},
    address = {Etonæ},
    author = {family={Dionísio Periegeta}},
    keywords = {Geography, Ancient -- sigla},
}

@book{Dionysius1974Tce,
    publisher = {Harvard University Press ; Heinemann},
    booktitle = {The critical essays},
    year = {1974},
    title = {The critical essays / Dionysius of Halicarnassus ; with an English translation by Stephen Usher.},
    address = {Cambridge, Mass. : London},
    author = {family={Dionísio de Halicarnasso}},
    keywords = {Essays -- Translations into English; Greek literature -- History and criticism; Rhetoric, Ancient; Literary style},
}

@book{Menander2019MR,
    year = {2019},
    title = {Menander Rhetor ; (Dionysius of Halicarnassus), Ars rhetorica / edited and translated by William H. Race.},
    author = {family={Menandro Retor}},
    keywords = {Rhetoric -- sigla},
}

@book{Didymus1975DtB2,
    publisher = {Hain},
    booktitle = {De trinitate, Buch 2, Kap. 1-7},
    year = {1975},
    title = {De trinitate, Buch 2, Kap. 1-7 / Didymus der Blinde ; hrsg. u. übers. von Ingrid Seiler},
    address = {Meisenheim am Glan},
    author = {family={Dídimo-o-Cego}},
    keywords = {Holy Spirit -- sigla},
}

@book{didymus2016commentary,
    title={Commentary on Genesis},
    author={family={Didymus (the Blind)}},
    url={https://books.google.pt/books?id=vQ-kDAAAQBAJ},
    year={2016},
    publisher={Catholic University of America Press},
}

@book{Pliny2013Pty,
    year = {2013},
    title = {Pliny, the younger : Epistles book II / edited by Christopher Whitton},
    language = {eng;lat},
    author = {family={Plínio-o-Moço}},
    keywords = {Plínio-o-Moço -- sigla},
}

\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[bibstyle=apa,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}



\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}


Um texto precisa de citações. Eis tal autor (\cite{Pliny2013Pty}), soubesse-o de cor!
Mas uma apenas não basta. Por isso, eis a segunda (\cite{Didymus1975DtB2}) e até uma terceira (\cite{didymus2016commentary}).
Uma citação é como uma muleta e eu preciso de outra agora (\cite{Menander2019MR}).
Fosse eu citado em obra de grande profundidade, de preferência, como esta (\cite{Dionysius1613Dop}).
Se só citar este autor (\cite{Dionysius1974Tce}) fosse garantia de que o li!

%\begin{refsection}[\jobname.bib]
\printbibliography[title=Coisas]
%\nocite{*}
%\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```